# Merge all keys into single object with the same Id in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

I have an array of objects Like that.

```
var orderResults = [{
    id: '1',
    name: 'Maya Mahardhani',
    payment_amount : 100,
    sku: 'ST001802027',
    seq: '1'
},
{
    id: '1',
    name: 'Maya Mahardhani',
    payment_amount : 50,
    sku: 'ST000703044',
    seq: '2'
},
{
    id: '2',
    name: 'Tara Debu Batara',
    payment_amount : 100,
    sku: 'ST005101001',
    seq: '1'
},
{
    id: '3',
    name: 'Nikita Gigir',
    payment_amount : 100,
    sku: 'ST004403030',
    seq: '1'
}]
```

But I am trying to extract the data in the following way.

```
[{
    id: '1',
    name: 'Maya Mahardhani',
    total_amount : 150,
    sku_1: 'ST001802027',
    sku_2: 'ST000703044',
},
{
    id: '2',
    name: 'Tara Debu Batara',
    total_amount : 100,
    sku_1: 'ST005101001'
},
{
    id: '3',
    name: 'Nikita Gigir',
    total_amount : 100,
    sku_1: 'ST004403030'
}]
```

I give try with the `reduce` function of JavaScript. But it overwrites the prev key with the old one. My Code Snippet is like that. I think I am closer to solve. But still seeking the help

```
orderResults.reduce((res, obj) => {
    res[obj.id] = { 
        total_amount : (obj.id in res ? res[obj.id].total_amount : 0)  + obj.payment_amount,
        name : obj.name,
    }

    res[obj.id]['sku' + obj.seq]= obj.sku
    return res;
},[])
```

Thank you

Comment: why not use an array instead of making sequential keys....

Comment: @epascarello, I need to print it that in xlsx. like it is just a requirement

Comment: res[obj.id] = res[obj.id] = || { your object code}; and than add to the total

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not create a new object every time.

```
const result = Object.values(orderResults.reduce((res, obj) => {
    res[obj.id] = res[obj.id] ||
    {   
        id: obj.id,
        total_amount : 0,
        name : obj.name,
    };
    res[obj.id].total_amount += obj.total_amount;
    res[obj.id]['sku' + obj.seq] = obj.sku;
    return res;
},[]))
```

Comment: Finally @epascarello, you are here. this is what I am looking for. I love you

Answer (score 1):

I think this will do what you are trying to do:

```
orderResults.reduce((res, obj, i) => {
    const existingIdx = res.findIndex(r => r.id === obj.id)
    if (existingIdx > -1) {
      res[existingIdx] = { 
        ...res[existingIdx],
        total_amount : res[existingIdx].total_amount ? res[existingIdx].total_amount + obj.payment_amount : res[existingIdx].payment_amount + obj.payment_amount,
        name : obj.name,
        ['sku_' + obj.seq]: obj.sku
      }
    } else {
      res.push({
        id: obj.id,
        name: obj.name,
        total_amount: obj.payment_amount,
        ['sku_' + obj.seq]: obj.sku
      })
    }

    return res;
},[])
```

Notice this line will preserve the original object and overwrite any duplicate keys that are defined afterwards:

`...res[existingIdx],`

Also when your code runs this line:

`res[obj.id] = {`

it is setting a specific index in the array, which I don't think you want to do. You want to either push (if the object id hasn't been added yet), or overwrite the existing object at the original insertion point when the object with the same id was created.

Answer (score 0):

```js
[{
    id: '1',
    name: 'Maya Mahardhani',
    payment_amount: 100,
    sku: 'ST001802027',
    seq: '1'
},
{
    id: '1',
    name: 'Maya Mahardhani',
    payment_amount: 50,
    sku: 'ST000703044',
    seq: '2'
},
{
    id: '2',
    name: 'Tara Debu Batara',
    payment_amount: 100,
    sku: 'ST005101001',
    seq: '1'
},
{
    id: '3',
    name: 'Nikita Gigir',
    payment_amount: 100,
    sku: 'ST004403030',
    seq: '1'
}].reduce((acc, current) => {
    const { id, name, payment_amount, sku, seq } = current;
    const previousRecord = acc[id];
    if (typeof previousRecord === 'object') {
        return {
            ...acc,
            [id]: {
                ...previousRecord,
                [`sku_${seq}`]: sku,
                total_amount: previousRecord.total_amount + payment_amount
            }
        }
    } else {

        return {
            ...acc,
            [id]: {
                id,
                name,
                [`sku_${seq}`]: sku,
                total_amount: payment_amount
            }
        }
    }
}, {}) // returns an Object; use Object.values to convert to a list
```